# IE Browser Caching issue with Angular 4

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I am new to Angular 4. I am working on an application which uses Angular 4 and Spring in the backend. One of the functionality in the application is to update the records from the UI. Problem in when i update the data ( it is basically the checkboxes which are to be checked/unchecked) , data is being saved successfully in databases. But when i navigate back to the same screen to view the updated field, it shows me old data ( even if i uncheck a few checkboxes) When we do debugging it shows that , data is being returned from the cache.

We tried different approaches like adding headers and adding no cache parameter but it did not help.

Comment: One way to prevent that is to add an additional parameter to your request to make it unique: `http://path/of/my/request?time=123456`, give it the current time with `Date.now();`

Comment: Tried this approach, even this is not working

Comment: Can you show us HTTP headers of stale data request and response? Note that BFCache may be involved. See [Make the bfcache in Internet Explorer work like Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825579/make-the-bfcache-in-internet-explorer-work-like-firefox) discussion on StackOverflow